# Changing the entire table on mouse over

Tags: html, css, html-table, mouseover

I have a very simple table for testing

```
<table>
<th>Header</th>
<tr><td>Somecontent</td></tr>
</table>
```

Now I surely can do

```
<th  onMouseOver="this.style.backgroundColor='#123456'" OnMouseOut="this.style.backgroundColor='#234567'" >Header</th>
```

but this would only only highlight the header. I cannot add this code to the  as it doesnt work. Any Idea how I can highlight the entire table on mouseover?

Comment: u want to change the color of the table

Comment: the html of your table is invalid, the `<th>` needs to be enclosed within a `<tr>`, which may optionally be enclosed by a `<thead>`. You should investigate in the css [`:hover` pseudo class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:hover) which is better suited for your use case.

Comment: You only want the table to be highlighted when the header is hovered over, correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Sebastian Heyn Please check following code. I hope you were expecting the same.

```css
table:hover {
    background-color: #FFEB3B;
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
<th>Header</th>
<th>Header</th>
</tr>
<tr><td>Somecontent</td>
<td>Somecontent</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using a combination of inline JS and CSS? Put this stuff in your stylesheet...

```
table:hover {
    background: red; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try my code.hope its may help u.

```css
.sample {
border:1px;
}
.sample th{
background-color:red;
}
.sample th:hover{
background-color:blue;
}
```

```html
<table class="sample" border=1>
<tr><th>Header</th></tr>
<tr><td>Somecontent</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: the idea was to change to entire table (header+rows) on mouseover on any of them

Answer (score 0):

Im not specialist , but maybe you should make table id and use some jquery  function.

Answer (score 0):

```css
th:hover,td:hover {
    background-color: #FFEB3B;
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
<th>Header</th>
<th>Header</th>
</tr>
<tr><td>Somecontent</td>
<td>Somecontent</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).